# What is wrong with my dynamically allocated array of pointers to structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I have the following program that references array elements through a double pointer.

```
typedef struct {
  int num1;
  int num2;
  int num3;
} DATA_SET;

typedef struct {
  int          structID;                                              
  DATA_SET     *data_set_array;  // Pointer to an array of DATA_SET structs
} MY_STRUCT;

int main () {
   MY_STRUCT   *Struct1;
   DATA_SET    **DataSetArray;   // Array of pointers

   Struct1 = malloc(sizeof(MY_STRUCT));
   Struct1->data_set_array = malloc(sizeof(DATA_SET*))  //Allocate mem for the pointer to array of DATA_SETs

   DataSetArray = malloc(sizeof(DATA_SET*) * 2)  // Allocate mem for an array of 2 DATA_SET pointers

   DataSetArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(DATA_SET))    // Allocate mem for the actual DATA_SET struct
   DataSetArray[0]->num1 = 1;
   DataSetArray[0]->num2 = 2;
   DataSetArray[0]->num3 = 3;

   DataSetArray[1] = malloc(sizeof(DATA_SET))    // Allocate mem for the actual DATA_SET struct
   DataSetArray[1]->num1 = 1;
   DataSetArray[1]->num2 = 2;
   DataSetArray[1]->num3 = 3;

   memcpy(Struct1->data_set_array, *DataSetArray, sizeof(DATA_SET*);  //Copy data set array into Struct1
```

When I print all the data out in Struct1, i get:

```
   Struct1->data_set_array[0].num1 = 1
   Struct1->data_set_array[0].num2 = 2
   Struct1->data_set_array[0].num3 = 3
   Struct1->data_set_array[1].num1 = 50       //This should be 1
   Struct1->data_set_array[1].num2 = 50       //This should be 2
   Struct1->data_set_array[1].num3 = 65       //This should be 3
```

Seems to be misuse/data corruption for the 2nd element in the array.

I know there's probably different ways to do this, but I wanted to get familiar with referencing the array indices via double pointers. Am I allocating memory properly? I have a feeling the memcpy is incorrect.

Comment: You allocated for DataSetArray twice the memory size for Struct1->data_set_array, and you copy half of that data.

Comment: Why do you want the variable `DataSetArray` and a memcpy? Just use `Struct1->data_set_array` - it will make your code much simpler.

Comment: Do you mean modify Struct1->data_set_array[0] explicitly? Don't I need to allocate memory for the structs?

Comment: "*`DATA_SET    **DataSetArray;   // Array of pointers`*" here `DataSetArray` is a pointer to pointer to `DATA_SET`. No array anywhere.

Comment: "*I wanted to get familiar with referencing the array indices via double pointers.*" this is very unclear, as as it stands does not really make sense. Perhaps it's a language issue? In any case please describe in more detail what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
Struct1->data_set_array = malloc(sizeof(DATA_SET*)
/*                                              ^ wrong */

DataSetArray = malloc(sizeof(DATA_SET*) * 2)
/*                                   ^ wrong */
```

You need to do `sizeof(DATA_SET)` because that is the actual size of a struct, not a pointer to a `DATA_SET` struct.

You're making the mistake of allocating only the size of a pointer times 2, which in many cases can be smaller than you'd hope for.

```
memcpy(Struct1->data_set_array, *DataSetArray, sizeof(DATA_SET*);
```

This is also wrong. You must copy the `sizeof(DATA_SET)`. Keep in mind that sizeof(DATA_SET) is not equal to sizeof(DATA_SET*). A pointer's size in bytes is the same regardless of the type of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with my dynamically allocated array of pointers to structs?

`DataSetArray` is an array of pointers to struct and there is **not** anything wrong with it.

The problem is 2 other things:

You can't use `memcpy` on an array of pointers to struct. The memory isn't consecutive.

Further, `data_set_array` is not an array of pointers to struct so you are trying to copy between incompatible types.

Comment: Ah. Should I change the data_set_array to a double pointer?
                                            
  DATA_SET     **data_set_array;  // Pointer to an array of DATA_SET

Comment: @user1224478 - It depends what you really are looking for. Do you want `data_set_array` to be `an array of structs` or do want `data_set_array` to be an `array of pointers to struct`? That is two different things. Your current code mixes those. In order to help you with the code, we first need to know you really want.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you basically want to create a Double Dimension array. So basically you can do the code like this

```
struct abc {
    int i;
};

struct abc **arr;
arr = (struct abc **) malloc(sizeof(struct abc) * 2);
arr[0] = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
arr[0]->i = 100;
arr[1] = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
arr[1]->i = 200;
```

One thing that you need to remember is that the outer array is just a pointer, so it doesn't need to be sizeof(abc) , it could very well be sizeof(int*) / sizeof (void*) etc.

so basically the above code could be written as

```
struct abc **arr;
arr = (struct abc **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2);
arr[0] = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
arr[0]->i = 100;
arr[1] = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
arr[1]->i = 200;
```

Hope this helps in underlying memory management you want to do with your code

Comment: In any case this `arr = (struct abc **) malloc(sizeof(...` should be `arr = malloc(sizeof(struct abc *) * 2);` or even better/more robust `arr = malloc(2 * sizeof *arr);`.

Comment: BTW, there is no need to cast void-pointers in C, nor is it recommended in any way,

Comment: alk  "BTW, there is no need to cast void-pointers in C, nor is it recommended in any way"   where did you get that recommendations from? Is it in standard ? if not then it doesn't matter as its only for coders and not the compiler.                            BTW, I am not sure what you're trying to say in here. May be there is a better way but it has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: The C11 Standard says that converting pointers to and from `void`-pointers is done implicitly. This is different from C++.

Comment: Also you might like to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc